# div with some opacity hiding fixed div upon page scroll

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#navigation {position: fixed;background-color: green;width: 100%;height:
80px;overflow: visible;}
#d1 {background-color: pink;width: 80%;height:600px; }
#d2 {background-color: yellow;width: 80%;height: 600px;opacity: 0.9;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation">
<h3>NAVIGATION MENU AREA</h3>
</div>
<div id="d1">
<br><br><br><br>
<h3>OPAQUE DIV</h3> </div>
<div id="d2"><h3>SEMI-OPAQUE DIV</h3> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon scrolling the page,fixed div "navigation" stays on top of div "d1" but as it comes to div "d2" it just goes behind it.How do i make div "navigation" to stay always on top of other div's,i don't want to alter the opacity on div "d2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-index specifies the stack order for your elements. You should apply z-index to any divs that you wish to place above or below other elements.

```
#navigation {
   position:fixed;
   background-color:green;
   width:100%;
   height:80px;
   overflow:visible;
   z-index:999 }
```

Further reading
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index